# Как распределить запросы между веб-сервером(Apache, nginx например) и Java-сервлетами?

Tags: java, веб-сервер, сервлеты

Есть бэкенд на Java, который предоставляет API для клиента. Т.е. `N` уникальных запросов определенного формата могут обработать `N` сервлетов.
Мне хочется сделать так, чтобы работал "серьезный" веб-сервер (как Apache скажем), который бы обрабатывал базовые запросы(загрузка файлов, скриптов и т.д.), а специальные запросы из API перебрасывались на Java-сервлеты.
Как это можно реализовать? Может есть инструменты для их интеграции?
или бэкенд на Java подразумевает написание своего веб-сервера, который бы делал все?

Comment: В терминах apache это называется reverse proxy и существует уже сто лет

Comment: Кроме того придумана какая-то штука специально для связки apache+сервер java. Называется AJP (Apache JServ Protocol)

Comment: Вам нужен nginx в роли реверс прокси, как и сказал Alexey Ten. А бэк можно и на GlassFish сделать, если правильно сбалансировать нагрузку. Апач более ресурсоёмкий для такой роли. Схема простая: nginx работает с простыми запросами и возвращает странички и статику всякую, а определённые запросы будет загонять на Ваш API, ровно как Вы и хотите. Если кэширование настроить правильно - всё будет работать без лишней нагрузки на бэк.